# Cannot reset firebase link from Crashlytics

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

From Crashlytics I had a number of links to firebase projects enabled. I had to remove some of the firebase projects with the aim of re-adding the Crashlytics projects to the new firebase projects I would create.

However, I cannot do this as not only has the Firebase link disappeared from within Crashlytics, when I visit the firebase integration page via the url - /firebase, it tells me 'Linked app not found'.

I have tried using the url https://fabric.io/remove_firebase_crashlytics?clientId=ios:com.remove.crashlytics.1&projectId=test-removing-crashlytics but to no avail. It tells me - 'Unable to find app ios:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.xxx.xxxx in project xxxxx-xxxx - I assume because the firebase project isn't there any more.

Is there any alternative way of removing/resetting the link?

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the answer, was able to add the link within firebase instead of through crashlytics via the 'Crashlytics' option in firebase to view crashes. From there you can link back to Crashlytics which fixes the link.

Comment: where is this link? I have the same problem.